# Generate variable names list with index

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 300 variables, I want to quickly generate a dataframe (or something else...) with the name of each variable and its index within the document. I have already found a bit of a sloppy way but was hoping to get something a bit nicer?

```
ID<-rep(LETTERS,length.out=9,each=3)
tsid<-rep(19:21,length.out=9)
turnover <-sample (1:100, 9)
fte <-sample (1:100, 9)
state <-rep(sample(1:6,3),each=3)
index<-1:5

dat1<-tibble(ID,tsid,turnover,fte,state)
dat2<-tibble(colnames(dat1),index)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you have is pretty much it - get the names and generate an index and put them together - `tibble(colnames(dat1), seq_along(colnames(dat1)))` - I don't think there'll be something a lot simpler.